# Returning true if a list has multiple strips of sequential months

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I am working a `C# list`  which is of type `DateTime` which has several rows of data in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and I am trying to figure a method which returns `true` if one of the following three conditions is `true`

1. If all the list items are equal ie. Equal Months and Years which is simple
2. If Month and Year are in sequence.

**Example:**

```
10/4/2016  
10/3/2016   
10/2/2016   
10/1/2016   
10/12/2015
```

In the above, `Month and Year` are in sequence so the method returns `true`.

3 . If the list has multiple strips of months in sequence

**Example:**

```
10/2/2016   
10/1/2016   
10/12/2015
10/2/2016   
10/1/2016   
10/12/2015
10/2/2016   
10/1/2016   
10/12/2015
```

In the above list, it has three strips of sequential months `12/2015,1/2016,2/2016`. So, for the above list it should return `true`. It should return `false` even if one month is out of sequence

I was able to write a method for the second condition in which dd/yyyy should be in sequence using the following method

```
for (var x = 1; x < terms.Count; ++x)
    {
        var d1 = terms[x - 1];
        var d2 = terms[x];


        if (d2.Year == d1.Year)
        {
            if ((d1.Month - d2.Month) != 1) return false;
            continue;
        }                              

        if ((d1.Year - d2.Year) != 1) return false;
        if (d1.Month != 1 || d2.Month != 12) return false;
    }
    return true;
```

**Is there a similar way I could do it to check third condition?**

Comment: *DateTime* is not in any format.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to

Comment: @Dev He's pointing out that a `DateTime` type has no concept of "a format". Format is how a DateTime is *presented*. A DateTime does not present the data, all it does is contain all of the components of a particular date and time.

Comment: Your third condition is unclear. Do you want to check for identical, repeated sequences ? Or are you simply looking for any number of sequences, of any size, as long as those sequences are in order ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're looking for here. *Any* sequence could be regarded as "multiple strips" where each strip is of length 1...

Comment: @JonathanM Yes, I want to check for identical,repeated sequences. it should return false even if a strip is in sequence but not identical to remaining strips

Comment: @JonSkeet Well yeah it can be of any length but all the strips should be identical. If it is of length 1 then obviously for the method to return true, the list should have same items which is my first condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use month and year, but consider adding time.

```
DateTime currentDateTime;
foreach(var d in terms)
{
  if(currentDateTime == default(DateTime))
  {
    currentDateTime = d;
  }
  else
  {
    currentDateTime = currentDateTime.AddMonths(1);
    if(currentDateTime != d) return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

For repeated of the same sequence (pseudocode this time):

```
// Determine initial sequence
while(currentDateTime.AddMonths(1) == nextDateTime) count++;

// Make sure that the whole sequence is a multiple of the short sequence
if(totalLength % count != 0) return false;

// Check remaining sequences
for(iteration in 1 .. totalLength / count)
  for(index in 1 .. count)
    if(terms[index] != terms[count * iteration + index]) return false;

// No elements differed
return true;
```

Comment: Do you mean to compare it with current Date time ot with the first item in the list?

Comment: I am a bit confused with usage of currentDateTime in the first block of code

Comment: It's just meant to be the loop variable... the value that you're working with currently.  Could be named currentValue if that would make more sense to you?  The comparison to default(DateTime) is essentially to initialize it, but using a foreach loop, it would basically want to be initialized when you look at the first value.